# How to execute the oracle 11g SP which resides in the package using EntityFrameworkCore 5

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, oracle11gr1

We are trying to execute the SP which resides in the package of oracle 11g. As of now we don't have any issues by querying the tables directly but we are facing issues while executing the SP from the package.

Error details:- "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement"

1. Get connection string :

   ```
   services.AddDbContext(options=>options.UseOracle(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
   ```
2. callingSP from package .

   ```
   Var list = _context.GetResultdetails.FromSqlRaw
   ("BEGIN Package.uspGetdetailsSP(:vrAccessID,:results); END;", parameters).ToList();
   ```
3. Fetching data from table

   ```
   var a = _context.species.FromSqlRaw("select * from DetailDB.table;").ToList()
   ```

Comment: Please mention what issue you are facing

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: updated error details